# How can I print the attributes and tags in XML parsing?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm parsing an XML file via Element Tree in python.

I want to print every tag and value in my xml file.

->This is my XML File

```
<EIT_PARSER>
          <EVENT>
                <VERSION>13</VERSION>
                <START_DATE>2018-03-14</START_DATE>
                <START_TIME>07:05:00</START_TIME>
                <DURATION>00:30:00</DURATION>
                <SHORT-DESCRIPTION>
                    <DESCRIPTION>
                        <LANG>tur</LANG>
                        <NAME>Tuhaf İcatlar</NAME>
                        <CODING>ISO-8859-9</CODING>
                    </DESCRIPTION>
                </SHORT-DESCRIPTION>
                <ID>651</ID>
                <FREE-CA-MODE>1</FREE-CA-MODE>
                <RUNNING-STATUS>0</RUNNING-STATUS>
                <EXTENDED-DESCRIPTION>
                    <DESCRIPTION>
                        <LANG>tur</LANG>
                        <TEXT>ŠSeloteyple, hazır kahvenin ortak noktası ne olabilir? Ya da Kleenex ve GPS Konumlama aygıtının? Şaşırmaya hazırlıklı olun! Bu dizi, en sıradan araçların neden ve nasıl keşfedildiğini ele alıyor.</TEXT>
                        <CODING>ISO-8859-9</CODING>
                    </DESCRIPTION>
                </EXTENDED-DESCRIPTION>
                <CLASSIFICATIONS>
                    <CONTENT>
                        <NIBBLE_LEVEL_1>9</NIBBLE_LEVEL_1>
                        <NIBBLE_LEVEL_2>0</NIBBLE_LEVEL_2>
                        <BROADCASTER_BYTE>4</BROADCASTER_BYTE>
                    </CONTENT>
                </CLASSIFICATIONS>
                <PARENTAL-RATING>
                    <RATING>
                        <COUNTRY_CODE>TUR</COUNTRY_CODE>
                        <AGE>0</AGE>
                    </RATING>
                </PARENTAL-RATING>
            </EVENT>
</EIT_PARSER>
```

My Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('y.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for event in root.findall('EVENT'):
    desc = event.find('SHORT-DESCRIPTION')
    if desc is None:
        continue
    desc_s = desc.text
    children = event.get('DESCRIPTION')
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to check the tags and then take their values.

How can I print all tags and values ?

Comment: in what main tag `EVENT` is located ?

Comment: <EIT_PARSER>
</EIT_PARSER>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need go down into tree to access deeper data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_data():
    root = ET.parse('data.xml')
    for event in root.findall('.//EVENT'):
        version = event.find('VERSION').text
        lang = event.find('SHORT-DESCRIPTION').find('.//LANG').text
        name = event.find('SHORT-DESCRIPTION').find('.//NAME').text
        lang2 = event.find('EXTENDED-DESCRIPTION').find('.//LANG').text
        text = event.find('EXTENDED-DESCRIPTION').find('.//TEXT').text
```

**Output:**

```
13
tur
Tuhaf İcatlar
tur
Seloteyple, hazır kahvenin ortak noktası ne olabilir?.....
```